# Hierarchical Query in MySQl vs SQLServer vs Oracle

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008, hierarchy

I am trying to implement the Connect By query in oracle/mysql/sqlserver to understand the difference in working. Trying to understand how it works. So I have a simple table which looks likes:

```
empno ename mno
1      KS    null
2      AB     2
3      BC     1
4      TR     3
5      QE     2
6      PL     3
7      LK     6
```

The Query in Oracle (working)

```
SELECT empno, ename, mno
   FROM test
START WITH ename = 'LK'
   CONNECT BY  empno = PRIOR mno;
```

The Query in SQLServer (not working):

```
WITH    q AS 
        (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    test
        WHERE   empno = 5
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  m.*
        FROM    test m
        JOIN    q
        ON      m.mno = q.mno
        )
SELECT  *
FROM    q
```

How do i do it in SqlServer  ? How does CTE exactly work ? and How would the same query look like in MySQL ?

### EDIT

Expected results returned from Oracle query are:

```
EMPNO   ENAME   MNO
7       LK      6
6       PL      3
3       BC      1
1       KS      (null)
```

[SQLFiddle (for Oracle) here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/750ce/1)

Comment: "How does CTE exactly work" --- have you tried to Google? Recursive CTEs are pretty well explained. You cannot do that in pure mysql's sql dialect though

Answer (score 1):

Your join condition is `m.mno = q.mno`, when I think you want `m.empno = q.mno`.